# WooCommerce display product thumbnail and add to cart button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a live search field that fetches the title of the product using AJAX.
It works correctly, however, I would like to fetch the product thumbnail and the ‘Add to the cart’ button.

**Edit: I have added the output for the thumbnail and add to cart button. It works, but it only displays in singular rows. How can I update my output in rows of 4 as below?
[image]

Front End Code

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()">

<div id="datafetch">Your numbers will show here</div>



<script>
function fetch(){

    $.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',{'action':'my_action'},
    function(response){
        $('#datafetch').append(response);
        console.log(result);
    });
}
</script>
```

Code in Functions.php

```
         <?php
}// LOTTERY start the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

        $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'product' ) );


    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();
    global $product;
        $product = get_product( get_the_ID() ); //set the global product object

$myquery = esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] );
$a = $myquery;
$search = get_the_title();
if( stripos("/{$search}/", $a) !== false) {?>
            <h4><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h4>
<h4><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a></h4>
<p><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
                        <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); //ouptput the woocommerce loop add to cart button ?>

        <?php
                                  }
    endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;

    die();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID())` to get thumbnail URL and add image.

You can use this `https://yourdomain.com/?add-to-cart=<product_id>` to add product add to cart URL.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/

Comment: I have tried get_the_post_thumbnail_url() which did not output anything. For the Add-to-cart, how does this solution become dynamic to the array of products in the search?

Comment: Can you share the code please with `get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID())`

Comment: Ok- I am able to output the post thumbnail. However, how can I dynamically add the add-to-cart button here?

Comment: Hi did you try out this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61058748/8328727? Also, I see a few more security vulnerabilities on you ajax call.  Pls fix that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
//Ajax
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'product' ) );

    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();

            $myquery = esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] );
            $a = $myquery;
            $search = get_the_title();
            if( stripos("/{$search}/", $a) !== false) {
                
                //get image and add-to-cart buttom here
                $query->the_post(); 
                global $product;
                wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
                //End get image and add-to-cart buttom here

            }

    endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;

    die();
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, it didn't display anything at all once I added.